# RenderPartial control in same view folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a file in my view folder `Users` called `UserViewControl.cshtml`.

My code in the actual view (`Users.cshtml`) is:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("RegisterViewControl")
```

Error:`The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments`

I do not want to type the path fully like this as the whole view folders might move in the future:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Users/RegisterViewControl.cshtml")
```

Code in **RegisterViewControl.cshtml**:

```
@model SampleMVC.Web.ViewModels.RegisterModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Auth", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "ERForm" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)        
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)            
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)          
}
```

This is a form that will be submitted by ajax, but I want all the validation from the viewmodel.

Comment: please post the code within UserViewControl.cshtml

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("RegisterViewControl");}
```

And that's because the `RenderPartial` extension method doesn't return anything. It writes directly to the output. In aspx you use it like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("RegisterViewControl"); %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial("RegisterViewControl") %>
```

So the same rules apply for razor.

Answer (score 7):

You could alternatively use

```
@Html.Partial("RegisterViewControl")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and got this directly from Scott Guthrie's blog post:

> using `@Html.RenderPartial()` from a Razor view doesnt work.
>
> Rather than call `Html.RenderPartial()` use just
>   `@Html.Partial("partialname")`
>
> That returns a string and will work.
>
> Alternatively, if you really want to use the void return method you
>   can use this syntax:
>
> `@{Html.RenderPartial("partialName")}`
>
> But `@Html.Partial()` is the cleanest.

The link for this is: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx